# When I used msp in fabric-sdk-go to register users with CA, an error occurred

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go

The error is as follows：

```
Register return error:
 failed to register user: failed to register user: Response from server: Error Code: 20 - Authentication failure
```

The relevant part of the code is as follows：

```golang
import (
[...]
mspclient "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/client/msp"
[...]
)

[...]

func RegisterUser(sdk *fabsdk.FabricSDK, info *InitInfo, r *RegistrationRequest) (string, error) {
    clientContext := sdk.Context(fabsdk.WithUser(info.OrgAdmin), fabsdk.WithOrg(info.OrgName))
    if clientContext == nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("根据指定的组织名称与管理员创建资源管理客户端Context失败")
    }
    // 创建一个新的msp客户端实例，并返回
    c, err := mspclient.New(sdk.Context(), mspclient.WithOrg(info.OrgName))
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("根据指定的 OrgName 创建 Org MSP 客户端实例失败: %v", err)
    }
    request := mspclient.RegistrationRequest{
        Name:           r.Name,
        Type:           r.Type,
        MaxEnrollments: r.MaxEnrollments,
        Affiliation:    r.Affiliation,
        //Attributes:     ,
        CAName: r.CAName,
        Secret: r.Secret,
    }
    _, err = c.Register(&request)
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("Register return error:\n %s\n", err)
    }
    return "enroll user is completed", nil
}
```

In this forum, I also found that someone reported the same error, and some people answered that the user name and password do not match, but my code is a registered user, this reason should not appear.

Comment: what's the `orgname`?

Comment: You mean  `orgname` in this sentence ：`"根据指定的 OrgName 创建 Org MSP 客户端实例失败: %v"`. The name of the organization in the channel.Is PeerOrgs-name in the `crypto-config.yaml`.

Comment: If you are using any other name except `org1` and `org2` then first you have affiliate that organization. By default, `org1` and `org2` are affiliated.

Comment: How do I establish affiliation with other organizations besides `org1` and `org2`?.Thanks for your answer.

Comment: hey @xu_liu, did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Below is the function I'm using. you can change it accordingly. Use it before `Registering` user.

```
/**
     1. In Hyperledger fabric by default "org1 & org2" are affiliated as CA organization, so any client or peer
            wants to register or enroll into the network via CA can pass "org1 or org2" as an affiliated organization.
     2. In case of other organization like org3 & org4, they need to be affiliated
**/

// AddAffiliationOrg : adding the affiliations of orgs. need to do this if Orgname isn't org1 or org2
func AddAffiliationOrg(setup *OrgSetup, caClient *msp.Client, caName string) error {

    orgName := setup.OrgName
    affl := strings.ToLower(orgName) + ".department1"

    fmt.Println("Initializing Affiliation for " + affl)

    affResponse, err := caClient.GetAffiliation(affl)

    if affResponse != nil && err != nil {

        fmt.Println("Affiliation Exists")

        AfInfo := affResponse.AffiliationInfo
        CAName := affResponse.CAName

        fmt.Println("AfInfo : " + AfInfo.Name)
        fmt.Println("CAName : " + CAName)
    } else {

        fmt.Println("Add Affiliation " + affl)

        _, err = caClient.AddAffiliation(&msp.AffiliationRequest{

            Name:   affl,
            Force:  true,
            CAName: caName,
        })

        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("Failed to add affiliation for CA '%s' : %v ", caName, err)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("\n Affiliation completed successfully")
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your meticulous answer. I will refer to your code to modify my project.

Comment: I used a function similar to AddAffiliationOrgto , but the error still exists.I’m posting the relevant code and output below, can you take a look at it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

```golang
func (t *ServiceSetup)AddAffiliationOrg(caName,orgName string) error {
 sdk, err := fabsdk.New(config.FromFile(sellerConfigFile))
 ctx := sdk.Context()
 caClient, err := msp.New(ctx)
 if err != nil {
  fmt.Printf("Failed to create msp client: %s\n", err)
  return  err
 }
  
    affl := strings.ToLower(orgName) + ".department1"

    fmt.Println("Initializing Affiliation for " + affl)

    affResponse, err := caClient.GetAffiliation(affl)

    if affResponse != nil && err != nil {

        fmt.Println("Affiliation Exists")

        AfInfo := affResponse.AffiliationInfo
        CAName := affResponse.CAName

        fmt.Println("AfInfo : " + AfInfo.Name)
        fmt.Println("CAName : " + CAName)
    } else {

        fmt.Println("Add Affiliation " + affl)

        _, err = caClient.AddAffiliation(&msp.AffiliationRequest{

            Name:   affl,
            Force:  true,
            CAName: caName,
        })

        if err != nil {
   fmt.Printf("Failed to add affiliation for CA '%s' : %v ", caName, err)
            return err
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("\n Affiliation completed successfully")
    return nil
}
```

Error:

```
Executing AddAffiliationOrg command
Initializing Affiliation for seller.department1
 [fabsdk/fab] 2020/09/28 02:12:42 UTC - n/a -> INFO generating key: &{A:ecdsa S:256}
 [fabsdk/fab] 2020/09/28 02:12:42 UTC - logbridge.(*cLogger).Info -> INFO encoded CSR
Add Affiliation seller.department1

 Affiliation completed successfully
Executing enroll command
Going to enroll user
 [fabsdk/fab] 2020/09/28 02:12:42 UTC - n/a -> INFO generating key: &{A:ecdsa S:256}
 [fabsdk/fab] 2020/09/28 02:12:43 UTC - logbridge.(*cLogger).Info -> INFO encoded CSR
Failed to enroll user: enroll failed: enroll failed: Response from server: Error Code: 20 - Authentication failure

Executing register command
register 225255 successfully,with password 462222
register success
```

Comment: I posted below.

Comment: I'm sorry what I meant was config file that you are using for `go-sdk`. your docker-compose file looks fine.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you mean.I put the `go-sdk` below.

Answer (score 0):

docker-compose-ca.yaml

```yaml
version: '2'
networks:
    default:
services:
  ca.seller.com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    container_name: ca.seller.com
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.seller.com
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.seller.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/57e5f37e597264cc2fa31c98d462c51796308cedd56fa8c09ea97a07b612679e_sk
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=false
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.seller.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/57e5f37e597264cc2fa31c98d462c51796308cedd56fa8c09ea97a07b612679e_sk
    ports:
      - 8054:7054
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/seller.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - ca.seller.com
  ca.buyer.com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    container_name: ca.buyer.com
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.buyer.com
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.buyer.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/78e27e6db18578fefd8a98fe74f8393e4cb5ee414e887f3325e4105239757727_sk
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=false
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.buyer.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/78e27e6db18578fefd8a98fe74f8393e4cb5ee414e887f3325e4105239757727_sk
    ports:
      - 7054:7054
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/buyer.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - ca.buyer.com
  ca.auctionhouse.com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    container_name: ca.auctionhouse.com
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.auctionhouse.com
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.auctionhouse.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/f9437970fbf01b1ff6e4e449aa14f762866bf0c96f193f62c444842f3b38624f_sk
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=false
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.auctionhouse.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/f9437970fbf01b1ff6e4e449aa14f762866bf0c96f193f62c444842f3b38624f_sk
    ports:
      - 9054:7054
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/auctionhouse.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - ca.auctionhouse.com
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the sdk config file of one of the organizations.

```yaml
version: 1.0.0

#
# The client section used by GO SDK.
#
client:

  # Which organization does this application instance belong to? The value must be the name of an org
  # defined under "organizations"
  organization: Seller

  logging:
    level: info


  # Root of the MSP directories with keys and certs.
  cryptoconfig:
    path: ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/baozhanglian/fixtures/crypto-config

  # Some SDKs support pluggable KV stores, the properties under "credentialStore"
  # are implementation specific
  credentialStore:
    # [Optional]. Used by user store. Not needed if all credentials are embedded in configuration
    # and enrollments are performed elswhere.
    path: "/tmp/state-store"

    # [Optional]. Specific to the CryptoSuite implementation used by GO SDK. Software-based implementations
    # requiring a key store. PKCS#11 based implementations does not.
    cryptoStore:
      # Specific to the underlying KeyValueStore that backs the crypto key store.
      path: /tmp/msp

   # BCCSP config for the client. Used by GO SDK.
  BCCSP:
    security:
     enabled: true
     default:
      provider: "SW"
     hashAlgorithm: "SHA2"
     softVerify: true
     level: 256

  tlsCerts:
    # [Optional]. Use system certificate pool when connecting to peers, orderers (for negotiating TLS) Default: false
    systemCertPool: false

    # [Optional]. Client key and cert for TLS handshake with peers and orderers
    client:
      key:
        path: 
      cert:
        path: 

#
# [Optional]. But most apps would have this section so that channel objects can be constructed
# based on the content below. If an app is creating channels, then it likely will not need this
# section.
#
channels:

  #[Required if _default not defined; Optional if _default defined]. 
  # name of the channel
  bzlchannel:

    # list of orderers designated by the application to use for transactions on this
    # channel. This list can be a result of access control ("FBI" can only access "ordererA"), or
    # operational decisions to share loads from applications among the orderers.  The values must
    # be "names" of orgs defined under "organizations/peers"
    # deprecated: not recommended, to override any orderer configuration items, entity matchers should be used.
#    orderers:
#      - orderer.baozhanglian.com

    #[Required if _default peers not defined; Optional if _default peers defined].
    # list of peers from participating orgs
    peers:
      peer0.seller.baozhanglian.com:
        # [Optional]. will this peer be sent transaction proposals for endorsement? The peer must
        # have the chaincode installed. The app can also use this property to decide which peers
        # to send the chaincode install request. Default: true
        endorsingPeer: true

        # [Optional]. will this peer be sent query proposals? The peer must have the chaincode
        # installed. The app can also use this property to decide which peers to send the
        # chaincode install request. Default: true
        chaincodeQuery: true

        # [Optional]. will this peer be sent query proposals that do not require chaincodes, like
        # queryBlock(), queryTransaction(), etc. Default: true
        ledgerQuery: true

        # [Optional]. will this peer be the target of the SDK's listener registration? All peers can
        # produce events but the app typically only needs to connect to one to listen to events.
        # Default: true
        eventSource: true

      peer0.buyer.baozhanglian.com:
       
        endorsingPeer: true

        chaincodeQuery: true

        ledgerQuery: true

        eventSource: true
        
      peer0.auctionhouse.baozhanglian.com:
       
        endorsingPeer: true

        chaincodeQuery: true

        ledgerQuery: true

        eventSource: true

# list of participating organizations in this network
#
organizations:
  Seller:
    mspid: SellerMSP

    # This org's MSP store (absolute path or relative to client.cryptoconfig)
    cryptoPath: peerOrganizations/seller.baozhanglian.com/users/{username}@seller.baozhanglian.com/msp

    peers:
      - peer0.seller.baozhanglian.com

    # [Optional]. Certificate Authorities issue certificates for identification purposes in a Fabric based
    # network. Typically certificates provisioning is done in a separate process outside of the
    # runtime network. Fabric-CA is a special certificate authority that provides a REST APIs for
    # dynamic certificate management (enroll, revoke, re-enroll). The following section is only for
    # Fabric-CA servers.
    certificateAuthorities:
      - ca.seller.baozhanglian.com

  # the profile will contain public information about organizations other than the one it belongs to.
  # These are necessary information to make transaction lifecycles work, including MSP IDs and
  # peers with a public URL to send transaction proposals. The file will not contain private
  # information reserved for members of the organization, such as admin key and certificate,
  # fabric-ca registrar enroll ID and secret, etc.
  Buyer:
    mspid: BuyerMSP

    # This org's MSP store (absolute path or relative to client.cryptoconfig)
    cryptoPath: peerOrganizations/buyer.baozhanglian.com/users/{username}@buyer.baozhanglian.com/msp

    peers:
      - peer0.buyer.baozhanglian.com
  

    # [Optional]. Certificate Authorities issue certificates for identification purposes in a Fabric based
    # network. Typically certificates provisioning is done in a separate process outside of the
    # runtime network. Fabric-CA is a special certificate authority that provides a REST APIs for
    # dynamic certificate management (enroll, revoke, re-enroll). The following section is only for
    # Fabric-CA servers.
    certificateAuthorities:
      - ca.buyer.baozhanglian.com 

  AuctionHouse:
    mspid: AuctionHouseMSP

    # This org's MSP store (absolute path or relative to client.cryptoconfig)
    cryptoPath: peerOrganizations/auctionhouse.baozhanglian.com/users/{username}@auctionhouse.baozhanglian.com/msp

    peers:
      - peer0.auctionhouse.baozhanglian.com

    # [Optional]. Certificate Authorities issue certificates for identification purposes in a Fabric based
    # network. Typically certificates provisioning is done in a separate process outside of the
    # runtime network. Fabric-CA is a special certificate authority that provides a REST APIs for
    # dynamic certificate management (enroll, revoke, re-enroll). The following section is only for
    # Fabric-CA servers.
    certificateAuthorities:
      - ca.auctionhouse.baozhanglian.com

#
# List of orderers to send transaction and channel create/update requests to. For the time
# being only one orderer is needed. If more than one is defined, which one get used by the
# SDK is implementation specific. Consult each SDK's documentation for its handling of orderers.
#
orderers:
  orderer.baozhanglian.com:
    url: localhost:7050

    # these are standard properties defined by the gRPC library
    # they will be passed in as-is to gRPC client constructor
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: orderer.baozhanglian.com
      # These parameters should be set in coordination with the keepalive policy on the server,
      # as incompatible settings can result in closing of connection.
      # When duration of the 'keep-alive-time' is set to 0 or less the keep alive client parameters are disabled
      keep-alive-time: 0s
      keep-alive-timeout: 20s
      keep-alive-permit: false
      fail-fast: false
      # allow-insecure will be taken into consideration if address has no protocol defined, if true then grpc or else grpcs
      allow-insecure: false

    tlsCACerts:
      # Certificate location absolute path
      path: ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/baozhanglian/fixtures/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/baozhanglian.com/tlsca/tlsca.baozhanglian.com-cert.pem

#
# List of peers to send various requests to, including endorsement, query
# and event listener registration.
#
peers:
  peer0.seller.baozhanglian.com:
    # this URL is used to send endorsement and query requests
    url: localhost:8051
    eventUrl: localhost:8053
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer0.seller.baozhanglian.com
      # These parameters should be set in coordination with the keepalive policy on the server,
      # as incompatible settings can result in closing of connection.
      # When duration of the 'keep-alive-time' is set to 0 or less the keep alive client parameters are disabled
      keep-alive-time: 0s
      keep-alive-timeout: 20s
      keep-alive-permit: false
      fail-fast: false
      # allow-insecure will be taken into consideration if address has no protocol defined, if true then grpc or else grpcs
      allow-insecure: false

    tlsCACerts:
      # Certificate location absolute path
      path: ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/baozhanglian/fixtures/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/seller.baozhanglian.com/tlsca/tlsca.seller.baozhanglian.com-cert.pem
  peer0.buyer.baozhanglian.com:
    # this URL is used to send endorsement and query requests
    url: localhost:7051
    eventUrl: localhost:7053
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer0.buyer.baozhanglian.com
      # These parameters should be set in coordination with the keepalive policy on the server,
      # as incompatible settings can result in closing of connection.
      # When duration of the 'keep-alive-time' is set to 0 or less the keep alive client parameters are disabled
      keep-alive-time: 0s
      keep-alive-timeout: 20s
      keep-alive-permit: false
      fail-fast: false
      # allow-insecure will be taken into consideration if address has no protocol defined, if true then grpc or else grpcs
      allow-insecure: false

    tlsCACerts:
      # Certificate location absolute path
      path: ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/baozhanglian/fixtures/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/buyer.baozhanglian.com/tlsca/tlsca.buyer.baozhanglian.com-cert.pem
  peer0.auctionhouse.baozhanglian.com:
    # this URL is used to send endorsement and query requests
    url: localhost:9051
    eventUrl: localhost:9053
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer0.auctionhouse.baozhanglian.com
      # These parameters should be set in coordination with the keepalive policy on the server,
      # as incompatible settings can result in closing of connection.
      # When duration of the 'keep-alive-time' is set to 0 or less the keep alive client parameters are disabled
      keep-alive-time: 0s
      keep-alive-timeout: 20s
      keep-alive-permit: false
      fail-fast: false
      # allow-insecure will be taken into consideration if address has no protocol defined, if true then grpc or else grpcs
      allow-insecure: false

    tlsCACerts:
      # Certificate location absolute path
      path: ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/baozhanglian/fixtures/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/auctionhouse.baozhanglian.com/tlsca/tlsca.auctionhouse.baozhanglian.com-cert.pem
  
# Fabric-CA is a special kind of Certificate Authority provided by Hyperledger Fabric which allows
# certificate management to be done via REST APIs. Application may choose to use a standard
# Certificate Authority instead of Fabric-CA, in which case this section would not be specified.
#
certificateAuthorities:
  ca.seller.baozhanglian.com:
    url: localhost:8054
    tlsCACerts:
      # Comma-Separated list of paths
      path: ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/baozhanglian/fixtures/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/seller.baozhanglian.com/tlsca/tlsca.seller.baozhanglian.com-cert.pem
      # Client key and cert for SSL handshake wit  h Fabric CA
      client:
        key:
          path: ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/baozhanglian/fixtures/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/seller.baozhanglian.com/users/User1@seller.baozhanglian.com/tls/client.key
        cert:
          path: ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/baozhanglian/fixtures/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/seller.baozhanglian.com/users/User1@seller.baozhanglian.com/tls/client.crt

    # Fabric-CA supports dynamic user enrollment via REST APIs. A "root" user, a.k.a registrar, is
    # needed to enroll and invoke new users.
    registrar:
      enrollId: admin
      enrollSecret: adminpw
    # [Optional] The optional name of the CA.
    caName: ca.seller.baozhanglian.com
  
  ca.buyer.baozhanglian.com:
    url: localhost:7054
    tlsCACerts:
      # Comma-Separated list of paths
      path: ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/baozhanglian/fixtures/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/buyer.baozhanglian.com/tlsca/tlsca.buyer.baozhanglian.com-cert.pem
      # Client key and cert for SSL handshake with Fabric CA
      client:
        key:
          path: ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/baozhanglian/fixtures/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/buyer.baozhanglian.com/users/User1@buyer.baozhanglian.com/tls/client.key
        cert:
          path: ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/baozhanglian/fixtures/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/buyer.baozhanglian.com/users/User1@buyer.baozhanglian.com/tls/client.crt

    # Fabric-CA supports dynamic user enrollment via REST APIs. A "root" user, a.k.a registrar, is
    # needed to enroll and invoke new users.
    registrar:
      enrollId: admin
      enrollSecret: adminpw
    # [Optional] The optional name of the CA.
    caName: ca.buyer.baozhanglian.com


  ca.auctionhouse.baozhanglian.com:
    url: localhost:9054
    tlsCACerts:
      # Comma-Separated list of paths
      path: ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/baozhanglian/fixtures/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/auctionhouse.baozhanglian.com/tlsca/tlsca.auctionhouse.baozhanglian.com-cert.pem
      # Client key and cert for SSL handshake wit  h Fabric CA
      client:
        key:
          path: ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/baozhanglian/fixtures/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/auctionhouse.baozhanglian.com/users/User1@auctionhouse.baozhanglian.com/tls/client.key
        cert:
          path: ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/baozhanglian/fixtures/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/auctionhouse.baozhanglian.com/users/User1@auctionhouse.baozhanglian.com/tls/client.crt

    # Fabric-CA supports dynamic user enrollment via REST APIs. A "root" user, a.k.a registrar, is
    # needed to enroll and invoke new users.
    registrar:
      enrollId: admin
      enrollSecret: adminpw
    # [Optional] The optional name of the CA.
    caName: ca.auctionhouse.baozhanglian.com
# EntityMatchers enable substitution of network hostnames with static configurations
 # so that properties can be mapped. Regex can be used for this purpose
# UrlSubstitutionExp can be empty which means the same network hostname will be used
# UrlSubstitutionExp can be given same as mapped peer url, so that mapped peer url can be used
# UrlSubstitutionExp can have golang regex matchers like $1.local.example.$2:$3 for pattern
 # like peer0.teachers.baozhanglian.com:1234 which converts peer0.teachers.baozhanglian.com to peer0.FBI.local.baozhanglian.com:1234
# sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp follow in the same lines as
 # SubstitutionExp for the fields gprcOptions.ssl-target-name-override respectively
# In any case mappedHost's config will be used, so mapped host cannot be empty, if entityMatchers are used
#entityMatchers:
#entityMatchers:
#  peer:
#    - pattern: (\w+).teachers.baozhanglian.com:(\d+)
#      urlSubstitutionExp: $1.teachers.baozhanglian.com:$2
#      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: $1.teachers.baozhanglian.com
#      mappedHost: peer0.teachers.baozhanglian.com
#
#
#    - pattern: (\w+).example1.(\w+):(\d+)
#      urlSubstitutionExp: $1.teachers.baozhanglian.com.$2:$3
#      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: $1.teachers.baozhanglian.com.$2
#      mappedHost: peer0.teachers.baozhanglian.com
#
#    - pattern: (\w+).teachers.baozhanglian.com.(\w+):(\d+)
#      urlSubstitutionExp: peer0.teachers.baozhanglian.com:7051
#      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: peer0.teachers.baozhanglian.com
#      mappedHost: peer0.teachers.baozhanglian.com
#
#  orderer:
#    - pattern: (\w+).example.(\w+)
#      urlSubstitutionExp: orderer.baozhanglian.com:7050
#      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: orderer.baozhanglian.com
#      mappedHost: orderer.baozhanglian.com
#
#    - pattern: (\w+).example2.(\w+)
#      urlSubstitutionExp: localhost:7050
#      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: localhost
#      mappedHost: orderer.baozhanglian.com
#
#    - pattern: (\w+).example3.(\w+)
#      urlSubstitutionExp:
#      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp:
#      mappedHost: orderer.baozhanglian.com
#
#    - pattern: (\w+).example4.(\w+):(\d+)
#      urlSubstitutionExp: $1.example.$2:$3
#      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: $1.example.$2
#      mappedHost: orderer.baozhanglian.com
#
#  certificateAuthority:
#    - pattern: (\w+).teachers.baozhanglian.com.(\w+)
#      urlSubstitutionExp:
#      mappedHost: ca.teachers.baozhanglian.com
#
entityMatchers:
  peer:
    - pattern: (\w*)peer0.seller.baozhanglian.com(\w*)
      urlSubstitutionExp: localhost:8051
      eventUrlSubstitutionExp: localhost:8053
      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: peer0.seller.baozhanglian.com
      mappedHost: peer0.seller.baozhanglian.com
    - pattern: (\w*)peer0.buyer.baozhanglian.com(\w*)
      urlSubstitutionExp: localhost:7051
      eventUrlSubstitutionExp: localhost:7053
      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: peer0.buyer.baozhanglian.com
      mappedHost: peer0.buyer.baozhanglian.com
    - pattern: (\w*)peer0.auctionhouse.baozhanglian.com(\w*)
      urlSubstitutionExp: localhost:9051
      eventUrlSubstitutionExp: localhost:9053
      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: peer0.auctionhouse.baozhanglian.com
      mappedHost: peer0.auctionhouse.baozhanglian.com
  orderer:
    - pattern: (\w*)orderer.baozhanglian.com(\w*)
      urlSubstitutionExp: localhost:7050
      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: orderer.baozhanglian.com
      mappedHost: orderer.baozhanglian.com

  certificateAuthorities:
    - pattern: (\w*)ca.seller.baozhanglian.com(\w*)
      urlSubstitutionExp: localhost:8054
      mappedHost: ca.seller.baozhanglian.com
    - pattern: (\w*)ca.buyer.baozhanglian.com(\w*)
      urlSubstitutionExp: localhost:7054
      mappedHost: ca.buyer.baozhanglian.com
    - pattern: (\w*)ca.auctionhouse.baozhanglian.com(\w*)
      urlSubstitutionExp: localhost:9054
      mappedHost: ca.auctionhouse.baozhanglian.com
```

Comment: this looks fine too. Can you please set logging level to debug and then check for sdk logs?
Also you can put this question to `https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/fabric-sdk-go` community.

Comment: I sent this question to `https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/fabric-sdk-go ` two weeks ago,but no one answered me.And I have a request. Can you share your registered user code with me？Thank you very much.